# i imported an FBX file and want to add bones

Tags: bones

well the title says it all... I am not understanding why the bones won't move the frame.
I imported the file and then used http://blog.digitaltutors.com/how-to-create-your-first-character-rig-in-blender-part-1/ to get it going.
when it got to the setting of vertexes part the skeleton was like 1/100th the size of the fbx file

Answer (score 1):

When importing models from other 3D computer graphics programs the model size is one of the main problems you will run into. The reason for this is that 3D computer graphics is not (necessarily) CAD. You don't have unified measurement units. Blender has a different internal measurement system than 3ds max, which uses a different one than Maya, and so on.

You need to resize your model to a reasonable size. The default grid floor is a good orientation point.

[image: model size]

You also want to change Blender's internal measurement units from "None" to "Metric" or "Imperial" (Metric works great for me).

Go to Properties Window, Select "Scene" panel, scroll down to "Units" and change the settings to your liking.

[image: change units]

This comes also in handy when exporting models to game engines.

Also be aware that the model's mesh isn't already triangulated. You simply won't have very much fun rigging it.